# SeekBar does not change its progress when I drag the thumb

Tags: android, seekbar

I have a seekbar in my Activity and want to process its onProgressChanged event when dragging the thumb.

I've implemented SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener (the code below) but there no any logging when I drag the thumb.

Thanks in advance.

```
<SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/durationSeekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:paddingStart="0dp"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp"/>
```

```
durationSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object: SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {


            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
                Log.i("singletrack","progress" + seekBar!!.progress)
            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
                Log.i("singletrack","progress" + seekBar!!.progress)
            }

            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                Log.i("singletrack","onProgressChanged " + progressAtStartTracking)
                    MediaPlayerHolder.getHolder().sessionAbsoluteDuration += progress
            }

        })
```

And there's one more strange thing (possibly, related with the topic problem): when I drag my thumb, there's some second strange thumb at the place where my "real" thumb was the first thumb. But this second thumb is non-draggable.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIMJS.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it! The problem was, *setOnSeekBarChangeListener()* is defined in the *onCreate()* method of the activity containing the fragment where  my seekbar is. I had to define *setOnSeekBarChangeListener()* in the *onViewCreated()* method of my fragment and not in the activity.

Also there is some bug with drawing the thumb. I had to set the thumb image programmatically because when I do so via .xml layout, it leaves track of the thumb on the start point.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onProgressChanged` function, shouldn't you be logging `progress` instead of `progressAtStartTracking`?  The `progress` variable is what shows you where the seekbar progress is currently located after it changes.

Comment: Yes, of course. But this line of log doesn't even appear like the others.

Comment: What is it logging?

Comment: it should log anything to ensure that the event has been processed but there no any logs. Program does not enter there.

Comment: Can you show your activity/fragment code and how you are initializing the seekbar? I've recreated your seekbar locally and it works fine.

Comment: Glad you were able to fix it!